# Angular: Nebular calendar: How to replace year and month section with custom text?

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm using Angular nebular library's calendar component. I need to translate month name and week days, so I tried to use calendar properties monthCellComponent and yearCellComponent. But nothing changes.

This is my code - calendar showing component:

```
<nb-calendar [(date)]="date" [showHeader]="false" 
            [dayCellComponent]="dayCellComponent" [yearCellComponent]="yearCellComponent">
</nb-calendar>
```

Custom year cell component

```
export class CalendarCustomYearCellComponent extends  NbCalendarYearCellComponent<Date>{}
```

Html file of the custom year cell comment has dummy text to replace month name.

[image]

-Need to change month name in here

Answer (score 1):

I have looked through the GitHub issues, found that [link](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1225). Hope, that helps